# facing template parse error while including ngx-bootstrap accordian

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap-accordion

showing error in the console-

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbAccordion" ("<ngb-accordion [ERROR ->]#acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
    <ngb-panel title="Simple">
```

Comment: how to use ngx-accordion in angular7

Comment: Hello, please explain what you want to do, what you have tried and what is the result. Also you should use code formatting : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code